# Propel ORM - Using setByName on a column from a delegated table

Tags: php, database, propel2

I'm using Propel ORM to make things easier in loading and saving a pretty large form to a database.  The form is huge but it's pretty much flat data, so it's essentially one big table (lets call it persons) with a couple hundred columns.  I don't want to have a couple hundred columns in one table so I have one master table and a bunch of one-to-one sub-tables.

I'm using the delegate behavior described [here](http://propelorm.org/documentation/behaviors/delegate.html).  This is nice because I can call `PersonQuery::create()->findPK($id)->toArray()` and it gives me not just the data in Person but also the data in every sub-table.  I can then load this data into my form very easily.

When a user edits the form and submits it, I send the form data to the server using POST.  I then iterate through that POST data in order to assign it to a person object and I use "`setByName`" to do this instead of the specific functions Propel provides.  So instead of doing this:

```
   $person = PersonQuery::create()->findPK($id);
   $person->setAge($_POST['age']);
   $person->setName($_POST['name']);
   //repeat for hundreds of columns
```

I can just do this:

```
$person = PersonQuery::create()->findPK($id);
foreach($_POST as $field=>$value){
   //before you ask, yes, i validate $field here
   $person->setByName($field, $value);
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that this doesn't work for my delegate tables.  So if I have my main table as Person, and I have a delegate table called Favorites, with a field Color, I can do `$person->setColor('Blue')`, but I can't do `$person->setByName('Color','Blue')`.

So... is there anyway I can do the above or something similar?  I really don't want to write out the setter for every column and have to update that list of setters whenever I change the database.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could have a lookup for fields.

```
$lookup = array('color' => 'setColor');

foreach ($_POST as $fieldName => $fieldValue) {
    if (isset($lookup[$fieldName])) {
        $func = $lookup[$fieldName];
        $person->$func($fieldValue);
    }
}
```

You don't need the lookup array, your function could be a concatenation of 'set' and ucwords($fieldName) = setColor

I don't recommend this as it could potentially be unsafe without the lookup.